# bootstrap col-sm-3 column doesn't go to second row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to organize a menu list. The code looks like below. My problem is the fifth column is not going to second row. It is getting attached with another columns white-space:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul>
      <li class="col-sm-3" style="background:grey; text-align:center"><a>1</a>
        <ul style="background:#ddd;">
          <li><a>2</a></li>
          <li><a>2</a></li>
          <li><a>2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="col-sm-3" style="background:grey; text-align:center"><a>2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>2</a></li>
          <li><a>2</a></li>
          <li><a>2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="col-sm-3" style="background:grey; text-align:center"><a>3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-sm-3" style="background:grey; text-align:center"><a>4</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="col-sm-3" style="background:grey; text-align:center"><a>5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Image:
[image]

How can I bring the 5 to second row? Is it must to write another div class="row ?

Comment: Just put it in a second div with class row?

Comment: I am trying to avoid the div class row. Because, I will implement it in a python template where menu items will come from a loop. Is there any way to do it by avoiding creating new div with row class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flexbox to make the lines wrap nicely.

Add the properties display:flex, flex-wrap:wrap to your top level ul

```
.container > .row > ul {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;
}
```

You may then need to address your styles

[example here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgoKEG)

Answer (score 1):

You need use class="row", to create a new row

```
<div class="row">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I could. But I am trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to display 5th option from the new line then follow this css.

```
li.col-sm-3:nth-child(5) {
    clear: both;
}
```

Make sure that this css only worked for 5th element only.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how many li items I will have. I can be five or fourteen or any number. I got the answer from hairmot.